# CSS height and width not applying to SVG

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I want to add heading to my graph.
Something like this :

[image]

I have tried append.svg , append.text....etc
but nothing seems to work. I,m just not able to write the correct CSS for
this i guess.

This code here works:

```
header= d3.select("svg").append("text")
    .attr("x", 70)             
    .attr("y", 20)
    .style("font-size", "16px") 
    .style("text-decoration", "underline")  
    .text("My graph heading...");
```

but i have problems in this one as i am unable to
assign it width and height and background fill.
When i assign it width or height it just does,nt gets applied.
Also changing the display to block is not working...

Running the code above makes a figure like this : 
My current graph picture

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could add a class/ID to it with d3, and then apply the styles with plain CSS instead of with d3? And/or: if changing display to block isn't working, I wonder if there is perhaps not a specificity issue, and whether `!important` might force it?

Comment: `svg` elements don't behave the same as `html` elements. try adding the `.style('text-anchor', 'center')` to your code. This is the alternative to `text-align: center` in css

Comment: @iulian is probably right and my comment is probably misleading / a waste of time. :-)

Comment: it's `text-anchor: middle`, not center

Comment: Okay once again...how can i make the heading tag go full width, display block and a part of the graph.

Comment: @SteveJax, did my solution helped you?

Comment: Well @iulian....my fellow programmer friends gave me the advice to append the heading separately with HTML code and not append it on run time in D3.js since it would require more time and space which would add further delay in making the graph.

But anyway thanks for your effort. Totally appreciate it.... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d3.select('svg').append('rect')
    .attr('x', 70)
    .attr('y', 20)
    .attr('width', 200)    // <-- your width here
    .attr('height', 100)   // <-- your height here
    .style('fill', 'red'); // <-- your color here

d3.select('svg').append('text')
    .attr('x', 170)      // <-- middle horizontal point of the rect (width/2 + leftMargin)
    .attr('y', 70)       // <-- middle vertical point of the rect (height/2 + topMargin)
    .attr('dy', '0.4em') // <-- tune this attribute to obtain perfect vertical alignment
    .style('text-anchor', 'middle') // keep your text centered
    .text('My graph heading...');
```

In the end, you will obtain this:

[image]